# Google App Engine serving 502s under light load

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, gunicorn, app-engine-flexible

I have a Django rest framework based API hosted on google app engine with 1 instance using gunicorn.

There is no scaling set up, yet. Here is the app.yaml :

```
runtime: custom
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
env_variables:
  DEPLOYMENT_MODE: prod
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

The instance has 1 CPU and 1 GB of memory and usually serves 4-6 requests per second. The application is working fine, but sometimes under light load, I intermittently get 502s, for no apparent reason. 
[image]

Ignore the spikes on left and right, they are because of an actual heavy load that the instance could not handle. The Intermittent 502s are highlighted.

I would like to understand the origin of these 502 errors.

Comment: I read that the default nginx keepalive_timeout is incompatible with the Google Cloud Platform HTTP(S) Load Balancer! Ref: https://blog.percy.io/tuning-nginx-behind-google-cloud-platform-http-s-load-balancer-305982ddb340

Comment: What do you see in your [logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#stackdriver_logging_and_the_flexible_environment)?